# Vim: Hightlight group not defined behind the end of the line in insert mode

Tags: syntax-highlighting, vim

I would like to define a few mappings that expand only when they are typed outside of comments and strings. The recommended way to detect if the cursor is located inside of a comment/string is (see `:help synID()`, for example):

```
if synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name") == "xxxComment"
```

However, this does not work well in the insert mode. If the cursor is behind the last character of the line, like in this example (`|` stands for the cursor):

```
some useful text    # Comment text|
```

function `synID()` always returns zero. Is this a 1) Vim bug, 2) syntax file bug, or 3) just a way syntax highlighting works?

Yep, I can always check the syn ID of the previous character, as in `synID(y, x-1, 1)`, but that makes the rest of script's logic more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd vote for 3), it's an artifact of how syntax highlighting works: It only considers characters that belong to the buffer, and the current cursor position (at the end of a line) is not yet part of the buffer.

I've worked around this in the same way as you suggest in one of my plugins, see [here](https://github.com/vim-scripts/IndentTab/blob/master/autoload/IndentTab/Syntax.vim#L17).

Comment: Ingo, thank you for you answer. Now I'm satisfied I haven't overlooked something. Just out of curiosity, what are those Long#Hashed#Function#Names useful for?

Comment: Those are (lazily loaded) autoload functions; see `:h autoload`.

Comment: A new horizon has opened for me, thanx! ;-)